# How to run existing Clojure programme in Sublime REPL

Tags: clojure, sublimetext2, read-eval-print-loop, sublimerepl

I have setup sublime REPL(Sublime 2, MAC) and able to run small Clojure programs like `(+ 2 2)`. I have created a small project using lein `lein new app clojure-noob` and I am able to run it via `lein repl`. And it loads the main class defined inside the project. How can I load the same main class in Sublime REPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is open your project's `project.clj` file in Sublime, make sure it has focus, then select **`Tools → SublimeREPL → Clojure → Clojure`**. This runs `lein repl` in `project.clj`'s folder.

If you'd prefer to not have to go through so many submenus to open the REPL, you can do this:

1. Select **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`** to open the `Packages` folder (`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`) in Finder.
2. Go to the `User` folder and create the following hierarchy: `Packages/User/SublimeREPL/config/Clojure`.
3. Create a new file in `Clojure` called `Main.sublime-menu` and open it in Sublime with the JSON syntax.
4. Add the following to the file:

   ```js
   [
        {
           "id": "tools",
           "children":
           [
               {"command": "repl_open",
                "caption": "Clojure",
                "id": "repl_clojure",
                "args": {
                   "type": "subprocess",
                   "encoding": "utf8",
                   "cmd": {"windows": ["lein.bat", "repl"],
                           "linux": ["lein", "repl"],
                           "osx":  ["lein", "repl"]},
                   "soft_quit": "\n(. System exit 0)\n",
                   "cwd": {"windows":"c:/Clojure",
                           "linux": "$file_path",
                           "osx": "$file_path"},
                   "syntax": "Packages/Clojure/Clojure.tmLanguage",
                   "external_id": "clojure",
                   "extend_env": {"INSIDE_EMACS": "1"}
                   }
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
   ```
5. Once you save the file, you will now have a **`Tools → Clojure`** menu option.