# How to run datomic repl inside sublimeREPL

Tags: clojure, sublimetext3, datomic

Datomic has a repl binary in bin/repl, how can I use this repl from within sublime text via sublime REPL?

This question is similar to this one: [How to run existing Clojure programme in Sublime REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042375/how-to-run-existing-clojure-programme-in-sublime-repl) but slightly different